# How to boxplot a subset of data versus the whole set in R?

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, lattice

I am using `bwplot` and I want to construct a boxplot of a subset of my data based on a factor variable, against the whole dataset.

For example:

```
library(MASS)
library(lattice)
data <- Cars93[,c("Manufacturer", "Price")] 
bwplot(data$Price~data$Manufacturer)
```

But rather than plotting each manufacturer, I just wanted to have two plots, one for say Chevrolet, and the other the entire dataset (including Chevrolet) - how would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why has this been down voted?

Comment: It was probably a harsh downvote, but I'm guessing it was because your code didn't run because you hadn't loaded the `lattice` package.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. That is a bit harsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new data.frame binding together all rows with just the Chevrolet subset, and then compare:

```
bwplot(Price ~ Manufacturer, data=rbind(
  transform(data, Manufacturer="All"),
  data[data$Manufacturer=="Chevrolet",])
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a need to creae a separate dataset. Just do this:

```
bwplot( Price~Manufacturer, data=Cars93, subset = Manufacturer=="Chevrolet")
bwplot( Price~Manufacturer, data=Cars93)
```

Comment: I was under the impression OP wanted both boxplots on the same plot, rather than generating two separate plots. Which is what makes the question tricky.

Comment: Yes that was what I was after.